# performance counter category 'Process' cannot be accessed on computer- VS load Test

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

When i run Load test using Vs Load Test i get an exception

The performance counter category 'Process' cannot be accessed on computer;check that the category and computer names are correct.   -   -

[image]

Comment: Is this being executed locally or via Microsoft's cloud service?

Comment: its executed Locally.

Comment: Configuring permisions etc is complex. Your question gives no details of how you have configured things and how much or, more likely, how little of Microsoft's instructions you have followed. My answer is based on Microsoft's instructions but it assumes that you have configured your users, your computers and so on correctly. You have not answered my question about whether Perfmon can see the counters. Without a lot more details in your question it is likely that this question will be closed. Please read [mcve] then [edit] the question give enough details to allow an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort out permissions etc to allow the user and computer running the tests to collect the performance counters from the remote machine. The short answer is that if the user running the tests cannot see the counters with Perfmon then Visual Studio will not be able to see them. Hence Perfmon can be used to give confidence that the settings are correct.

To enable collection of performance counters by a Visual Studio load test do the following in each remote computer to be monitored. Perform these steps while logged in to a sufficiently privileged account.

1)  Run `wf.msc`. In the `inbound` category, enable the `Performance Logs & Alerts firewall exception`.

2)  Run `lusrmgr.msc`. Add the user to the `Performance Log Users`, the `Performance Monitor Users` and the `Event Log Readers` groups. The user to be added is the user who will be running the tests.

3)  Run `services.msc`. Ensure the `Performance Logs & Alerts` and the `Remote Registry` services are set to autorun.

4)  Run `secpol.msc`. Ensure that the `Performance Log Users` and the `Performance Monitor Users` groups include the `Log on as a Batch User` privilege.

5)  At a command prompt rebuild all counters on the machine by running `lodctr /r`. (Have seen this command returning the message `Error: Unable to rebuild performance counter setting from system backup store, error code is 5`. Have not tracked down the reason but it does not appear to cause any problems.)

These commands are explained in more detail [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/edglas/2008/11/18/reading-performance-counters-on-vista-and-server-2008-machines/).

Comment: Tried all these , still getting the same exception.The performance counter category 'Process' cannot be accessed on computer 'Pc' (Category does not exist.) ; check that the category and computer names are correct.

Comment: You have tried all what? Can Perfmon see the counters when run from the correct account and on the Visual Studion counter? What is the actual error message you are getting? The screenshot in your question is irrelevant to to problem.